Surface integral of $f(x,y,z)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ over paraboloid surface portion $2z=x^2+y^2$ inside cylinder $2y=x^2+y^2$
Problem
Let $B$ be the paraboloid of the equation $2z=x^2+y^2$ and $C$ the cylinder of the equation $2y = x^2 + y^2$. Calculate the mass of the portion of $B$ within $C$ if the superficial density of $B$ is described by $f(x,y,z)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$
Attempt
Let $S$ be the portion of $B$ within $C$. In the $XY$ plane, $C$ is projected to the circle: $1 = x^2 + (y-1)^2$. The intersection of $B$ and $C$ is an ellipse in the plane $y=z$. From this, the projection of $S$ on the plane $XY$ is $1 = x^2 + (y-1)^2$, on the plane $XZ$ is $1 = x^2 + (z-1)^2$ and on the plane $YZ$ is the region inside the curves $2z = y^2$ and $z=y$.
The paraboloid surface can be expressed by a 3 variable function. $g(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2-2z = 0$, from which the gradient:
$$\nabla g = (2x,2y,-2)\quad ; \quad \Vert \nabla g \Vert = 2\sqrt{x^2+y^2+1}$$
Where
$$ \frac{\partial{g}}{\partial{x}} = 2x;\quad \frac{\partial{g}}{\partial{y}} = 2y;\quad \frac{\partial{g}}{\partial{z}} = -2$$
$$ dS = \frac{\Vert \nabla g \Vert}{\frac{\partial{g}}{\partial{z}}}dx\,dy = \sqrt{x^2+y^2+1}\,dx\,dy$$
$$ dS = \frac{\Vert \nabla g \Vert}{\frac{\partial{g}}{\partial{y}}}dx\,dz = \frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+1}}{|y|}\,dx\,dz = \frac{\sqrt{2z+1}}{\sqrt{2z-x^2}},dx\,dz$$
$$ dS = \frac{\Vert \nabla g \Vert}{\frac{\partial{g}}{\partial{x}}}dy\,dz = \frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+1}}{|x|}\,dy\,dz = \frac{\sqrt{2z+1}}{\sqrt{2z-y^2}},dy\,dz$$
I've tried to resolve the integral by projections on $XY$ plane, $D$ is the region inside the circle $1 = x^2 + (y-1)^2$, the mass of the surface $S$ is:
$$M = \iint_S f(x,y,z)\;dS = \iint_{D} \sqrt{x^2+y^2+1}\; \sqrt{x^2+y^2+\left(\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}\right) ^2}\;dx\,dy $$
Taking polar coordinates: $x = rcos(\theta),\;y = rsin(\theta),\; dx\,dy = r\,dr\,d\theta$, the integral can be written as:
$$M = \int_{\theta=0}^{\pi} \int_{r=0}^{2sin(\theta)} \frac{r^2}{2}\,\sqrt{r^2+4}\,\sqrt{r^2+1} \,dr \,d\theta$$
After that, it seems like it will be needed to use elliptic integrals, so I tried to project on planes $XZ$ and $YZ$ instead.
On $XZ$ plane, $D$ is the region inside the circle $1 = x^2 + (z-1)^2$, then:
$$M = \iint_S f(x,y,z)\;dS = \int\int_{D} \sqrt{2z+z^2}\; \frac{\sqrt{2z+1}}{\sqrt{2z-x^2}}\;dx\,dz $$
The integrand is even with respect to $x$, so the mass can be expressed as:
$$M = 2 \int_{z=0}^{2} \int_{x=0}^{\sqrt{1-(z-1)^2}} \,\sqrt{2z+z^2}\; \frac{\sqrt{2z+1}}{\sqrt{2z-x^2}} \,dx \,dz$$
$$M = 2 \int_{0}^{2}\,\sqrt{2z+z^2}\,\sqrt{2z+1}\;sin^{-1}\left(\sqrt{1-\frac{z}{2}}\right)\,dz$$
Which is an integral I couldn't solve.
On $YZ$ plane $D$ is the region inside the curves $2z = y^2$ and $z=y$. The surface $S$ is symetric respect to $YZ$ plane and $f$ is even with respect to $x$ then:
$$M = 2 \int_{z=0}^{2} \int_{y=z}^{\sqrt{2z}} \,\sqrt{2z+z^2}\; \frac{\sqrt{2z+1}}{\sqrt{2z-y^2}} \,dy \,dz = 2 \int_{0}^{2}\,\sqrt{2z+z^2}\,\sqrt{2z+1}\; \left(\frac{\pi}{2} - sin^{-1} \left(\sqrt{\frac{z}{2}}\right)\right)\,dz$$
In which I get the same integral as when projecting on $XZ$ plane:
$$M = 2 \int_{0}^{2}\,\sqrt{2z+z^2}\,\sqrt{2z+1}\;sin^{-1}\left(\sqrt{1-\frac{z}{2}}\right)\,dz$$
Is there any other way to evaluate the integral, or parametrize the surface to get to more 'solvable' integrals and get the answer?.
Thank you very much.
